# Google Maps with Refreshing Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is my first time posting on here, I am always reading solutions that are great. I have become stuck, and I am not too sure if I am going down the right path.

Basically I want to display the position of a number of cars on a Google Map, now I am getting the GPS info via another Program and the data is being updated to a MS Access Database. I require the page to just refresh the markers every 10 seconds, and the traffic data every 5 min.

P.S. I know MS Access databases are old hat, that's another story which should be changing soon!

Here is my UPDATED page code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <% 
'declare the variable that will hold new connection object
Dim Connection    
'create an ADO connection object
Set Connection=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'declare the variable that will hold the connection string
Dim ConnectionString 
'define connection string, specify database driver and location of the database 
ConnectionString="PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source= c:\easybook\tables.mdb" 

'open the connection to the database
Connection.Mode=adModeRead
Connection.Open ConnectionString 
%>
<head>
<title>Live Map Display</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
<link href="assets/css/ticketstyle.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

var map;
var mapMarkers = [];   // Array is declared and initialized here

function initialize() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 14,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.39659541993,-2.54446649561),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
        trafficLayer.setMap(map);

    var auto_remove = true;

    /*window.setInterval(function() {loadMarkers()}, 1000); // refreshes every 10 seconds*/
};

function loadMarkers () {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapMarkers.length; i++) {
        mapMarkers[i].setMap(null); // removes marker from the map
    }
    mapMarkers = []; // reinitialize the array

    var markers = document.getElementsByTagName("car");

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        location = {
            label : markers[i].getAttribute("label"),
            icon : markers[i].getAttribute("image"),
            labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
            pointlat : parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
            pointlng : parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))   
        };

        console.log(location);

        mapMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.pointlat, location.pointlng),
                map: map,
                labelClass: "label", // the CSS class for the label
                label : markers[i].getAttribute("label"),
                icon : markers[i].getAttribute("image"),
            })
        );
    }
    document.getElementById('car');
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<%
'declare the variable that will hold our new object
Dim Recordset   
'create an ADO recordset object
Set Recordset=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 

'declare the variable that will hold the SQL statement
Dim SQL    
SQL="SELECT * FROM cartable WHERE stat>0"
Dim carno, stat, Lat, Lng
'Open the recordset object executing the SQL statement and return records 
Recordset.Open SQL, Connection
%><%
'first of all determine whether there are any records 
If Recordset.EOF Then
Response.Write("") 
Else 
'if there are records then loop through the fields 
%>
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-left">
        <h1>MapLive</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="header-right">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="main">

<cars>    
<%Do While NOT Recordset.Eof  %> 
<car lng='<%Response.write Recordset("long")%>' lat='<%Response.write Recordset("lat")%>' label='<%Response.write Recordset("carno")%>' image='assets/images/loc-stat<%Response.write Recordset("stat")%>.png'/>
<%Recordset.MoveNext     
Loop
End If
%>
</cars>

<div id="map"></div>
</div>

</body>
<% 
Recordset.Close
Set Recordset=Nothing
Connection.Close
Set Connection=Nothing
%>
</html>
```

Hope someone can shed some light, how I refresh the markers, been scratching my head, and other examples I look at are coded differently, I am guessing this is Google Maps API v3.

Thanks for your time in advance...

Dean

Answer (score 0):

The easiest will be to reference the markers in an array globally and then `.push(new google.maps.Marker({...})` onto your array. You'll then want a timer on the page that runs through the array and set the markers map to null to remove them from the map via `setMap(null)`.

```
var map;
var mapMarkers = [];   // Array is declared and initialized here

function initialize() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 14,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.39659541993,-2.54446649561),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
        trafficLayer.setMap(map);

    var auto_remove = true;

    window.setInterval(function() {loadMarkers()}, 10000); // refreshes every 10 seconds
};

function loadMarkers () {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapMarkers.length; i++) {
        mapMarkers[i].setMap(null); // removes marker from the map
    }
    mapMarkers = []; // reinitialize the array

     var image = {
        size: new google.maps.Size(16, 26),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(8, 26)      
    }; // this isn't being used?

    var markers = document.getElementsByTagName("car");

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        location = {
            label : markers[i].getAttribute("label"),
            icon : markers[i].getAttribute("image"),
            labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
            pointlat : parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
            pointlng : parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))   
        };

        console.log(location);

        mapMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.pointlat, location.pointlng),
                map: map,
                labelClass: "label", // the CSS class for the label
                label : markers[i].getAttribute("label"),
                icon : markers[i].getAttribute("image"),
            });
        );
    }
    document.getElementById('car').addEventListener('100', cars);
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am struggling to code that. Can you give me an example, on how to use arrays at all?

Comment: I have added how to do this in my edit. To make it simple, I made the array global. The window.setInterval will call the function `loadMarkers` every x milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks, got en SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list on line 56.

Comment: You'll have to provide more information. What line of code does that put the error? Also, make sure to check my edit.

Comment: I have updated the code in my first post, nothing seams to be displaying on the map, and when it refreshes I get the 404 error page with the file name replaced with [object%20Object]?

Comment: Still trying to get this to work, still got the issues with the markers not display on the map and the reload producing  [object%20Object] issue.